# When I Build and Run my iPhone Application on the simulator, Only a White screen Comes Up

Tags: iphone

I don't know what could be causing this. I chose "View Based Application". I just installed the newer (although not the newest) version of xCode, so to try it out, I made a tester application. I made a button that when clicked, alternates a label between shown and hidden. The program ran, no errors or warnings, but when the sim. brings it up, all there is is a blank screen with no button or label. I am truly clueless...

```
    $- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}
$

I don't know if there is something corrupt with this App Delegate method, but it seems as though that may be the problem (as this is the method loading and making the .xib file visible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

If it is still not working, I would recommend making a duplicate project and just copying and pasting the App Delegate code from that into your current project.

Comment: That's weird, because even when I create a new file, the same thing happens. Should I install the newest v. of xCode?

Comment: Also make sure that the view controller is defined correctly in the AppDelegate.h file AND that a view controller is inserted in the MainWindow.xib file, and everything is linked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you create the button, do you add the button to the view? It would be done like this

```
[viewController.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Ok. Cool. In IB, is the UIButton contained by the view?

You can check this by opening the hierarchical view of your xib objects.  

1) Select your xib file from the list on the far left. Then, you should see a graphical display of your xib on the right, and there between the section that looks like graph paper and the list of files is an area where you can inspect you xib objects. 

2) If that is just a few icons on a narrow strip, click the tiny button at the bottom that looks like a Play button, and it will open up to show you a hierarchical view of all of the objects in the xib.